# How to populate StaggeredGridView

Tags: android, gridview, populate

I have been experimenting with StaggeredGridView (https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView), the custom GridView implementation found on Github. I downloaded it, and added it as a library to my project. I can instantiate the StaggeredGridView, but I'm not really clear yet on how to populate it. Does it use an adapter? And if so, what kind of adapter?

Answer (score 0):

> Does it use an adapter? And if so, what kind of adapter?

This example project > [Link](https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridViewDemo) shows how you can populate and display images using an `ArrayAdapter<...>`. But, from what I could tell, extending `BaseAdapter` should work fine as well.

Instead of URLs, you can pass resource IDs, image URIs from the gallery etc., and handle them in the overridden `getView(int, View, ViewGroup)` method.